# Mount a USB NIC to a VM guest in Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I have a Belkin USB Ethernet adapter which is actually required as a dongle for a certain Arm compiler to run (tied to MAC).  How can I make this available to a Windows XP VM within Hyper-V, which is running on a Server 2008 R2 instance?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Hyper-V doesn't have USB pass-through.

However, if you know the MAC of the NIC, you could just add a NIC to the VM with that MAC address.

Comment: if the mac is all they are using then this is not much use since you can edit the mac address of most nics.

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy. I recently went through this with a SafeNet Sentinel Pro USB licensing dongle. It's ugly and I was ultimately unsuccessful.

As @longneck noted, Hyper-V does not support USB pass-through. I haven't worked with Hyper-V on Windows Server 2012 but a quick Google shows that USB pass-through wasn't implemented.

Your workaround is to use a 3rd party product that "exports" the USB connection from the Hyper-V host to your Windows XP guest across the network. Examples of these products are  Fabulatech and KernelPro's USB Over Ethernet software. You could additionally use a network-capable USB hub to perform the same task.

You still have two more hurdles to get over. First is that you'll probably need to install some kind of driver on whatever host is physically hosting the USB dongle. With the SafeNet Sentinel implementation the driver installed successfully but did not recognize the USB device on the Hyper-V host, a Windows Server 2008 R2 Core installation (e.g., it showed up as unknown USB device in Device Manager).

Secondly you'll need to deal with the MAC address restriction. You will need to manipulate the MAC address of your Windows XP guest operating system to match the one your licensing device expects. This should be simple in Hyper-V by manually setting the MAC Address for the Windows XP's NIC manually in its virtual machine settings. I have no idea how the MAC address restriction will react to being exported across the network since at this point you're involving two MAC addresses in this chain. Depending on the sophistication of licensing mechanism it may balk at this.

It's worth noting that all of this kind of behavior, even though it is arguably legitimate, is exactly the kind of thing these USB licensing dongles are created to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to set up a host machine with VMWare's ESXi, or Oracle's VirtualBox and move your VM to that system. They do support USB passthru. I have the same sort of issue on my personal laptop, I wanted to hook up an old Extigy sound card and use it with an XP VM. I built the VM in Hyper-V under Windows 8 because it was already there, not realizing that hyper-V didn't have USB.

I was relatively impressed with my limited dive into MS Hyper-V on Win8 and Server2012 until I saw that.